# How to display embedded images in IE7?

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, encoding, base64

I am trying to display embedded image in IE7. The image is encoded in base64 encoding.

```
"src="data:image/jpg;base64"
```

This is what I tried..

I dowloaded the encoder / decoder script from below link.

http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html

I tried to decode the image but I am getting invalid pointer error, not sure why. Can someone let me know a way to display embedded pictures in IE7?

I used this link: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/

```
var BASE64_DATA = /^data:.*;base64/i;
        function fixBase64(img) {
            if (BASE64_DATA.test(img.src)) {
                document.writeln(Base64.decode(img.src.slice(5))); // Just trying to display the picture in screen 
            }
        };

            for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
                fixBase64(document.images[i]);
            }
```

Thanks,
Barani

Comment: Probably related: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688188, but not the solution.

Comment: you can't add this feature or behaviour using js, but you might get lucky using mhtml.
check out this link http://www.phpied.com/mhtml-when-you-need-data-uris-in-ie7-and-under/

Comment: Just to bring another solution: Drop IE7 support. It is down to 1% world wide usage. Only WindowsXP and older uses IE7. These operating systems are no longer supportet bby MS. As far as I know, jquery drops IE8 support in version 2.0

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach Windows Vista comes with IE7

Comment: But has an update path to IE8

Answer (score 1):

The invalid pointer error still occurs in older IE8 builds, but you can workaround it by referring to the SRC in the image attributes collection, i.e. instead of this:

```
img.src
```

use this:

```
img.attributes.src.value
```